# What does ORDER BY within OVER() window function mean in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am trying to understand how the `ORDER BY` clause in the `OVER()` window function is different from `ORDER BY` clause in generic SQL.

I was solving the following problem: https://www.pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/nummembers.html

```markdown
Produce a monotonically increasing numbered list of members (including guests),
ordered by their date of joining. Remember that member IDs are not guaranteed to be sequential.
```

The following query is one of the accepted solutions:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER by joindate), firstname, surname FROM cd.members;
```

As per my understanding, since we are not supplying a `PARTITION BY` clause in the `OVER()` function, all the rows in `cd.members` table form one big partition (let's call it X). When the window function runs, it should order X by joindate, and then `COUNT(*)` on X would return the number of rows in X which is just the number of rows in `cd.members`.

But this understanding is incorrect. The 'Answers and Discussion' accompanying the aforementioned problem states:

> Since we define an order for the window function, for any given row the window is: start of the dataset -> current row.

The [PG documentation on window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html) states:

> You can also control the order in which rows are processed by window functions using ORDER BY within OVER. (The window ORDER BY does not even have to match the order in which the rows are output.)

What I cannot comprehend is why will `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` ***stop*** at the current row? Could you please elaborate how this is working?

Thank you for reading through.

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/blog/2019-02/postgresql-11#over

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what to add beyond what the docs (same page as you already linked to) already say:

> By default, if ORDER BY is supplied then the frame consists of all
> rows from the start of the partition up through the current row, plus
> any following rows that are equal to the current row according to the
> ORDER BY clause.

I don't now if this required by the SQL standard, but it certainly seems reasonable.  Why specify an ORDER BY if you expect it to have no observable effect?