# Postgres window function count(*), unexpected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

After 15 years of having Postgres doing the heavy lifting, now for the first time I've found an unexpected result, dealing with a window function.

Here's an example where a `count(*) over (partition by ...` is disrupted if an `order by ...` is added:

```
create temp view cc as
select * from
(   values
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (2,1),
    (2,2),
    (2,3)
) as t(key1, key2) ;

select *,                       -- correct result
    count(*) over (             -- count(*) works, order unspecified
        partition by key1
    )
from cc order by key1,key2;

select *,                       -- incorrect result
    count(*) over (             -- count(*) fails, order is specified
        partition by key1 order by key2
    )
from cc order by key1,key2;
```

The example above produces:

```
 key1 | key2 | count      -- correct result
------+------+-------
    1 |    1 |     2      
    1 |    2 |     2
    2 |    1 |     3
    2 |    2 |     3
    2 |    3 |     3
(6 rows)

 key1 | key2 | count      -- incorrect result
------+------+-------
    1 |    1 |     1      -- should be 2
    1 |    2 |     2      
    2 |    1 |     1      -- should be 3
    2 |    2 |     2      -- should be 3
    2 |    3 |     3
(6 rows)
```

I need the extra 'order by' to establish who's the group leader.

Thanks in advance,
Ariel Tejera

Comment: And what is the (third) output you actually want to see here?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613813/what-does-order-by-within-over-window-function-mean-in-postgresql) SO thread should answer your question. I think that it is a _very_ useful feature.

Comment: The output you expect to see appears to be identical to the output you do see without the ORDER BY.  There is no visible indication of the group leader being established, whatever that means.

Comment: Thanks for your support, my intention was to show that the change in the 'over ..' generates different outputs, marked as 
-- correct result
-- incorrect result.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the frame clause in window functions and what it defaults to; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With `ORDER BY`, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer. Without `ORDER BY`, this means all rows of the partition are included in the window frame, since all rows become peers of the current row.

So your second query produces a “running count”, which will give you the same result as `row_number()`.

Comment: Great ! it sound like you are right, give me a little time to check (and undertand ) the "framing option" specs.  Most grateful.

Comment: Yep it worked as follows:
select *, count(*) over www from cc
    window www as (partition by key1 order by key2 range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
    order by key1,key2;
Thanks!